# How can I encode over/under metadata for 3D videos to upload to YouTube using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, 3d

I’ve been using

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264opts frame-packing=3 output_file.mp4
```

But not been having any luck with everything I’ve found so far.

Comment: What is "ou metadata"? What is the actual issue you are encountering?

Comment: I can’t get YouTube to play the file as a 3D one.  3D files are either sbs or over under / top bottom. The metadata is needed to let YouTube know what type it is.

Comment: See https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7278886?hl=en. Show exactly what you've tried and include the full ffmpeg log.

Comment: Thanks but that information is incorrect :( , I’m not sure why they put it up there.